# How to Stop Camera function after 10 secs countdown?

Tags: android

Hello guys I am working on my app using Android Studio.

In my app I need to stop the camera if user didn't take any picture after 10 secs of countdown.
So I need these functionalities given below

- Open Camera button.
- Camera Opened with 10 secs countdown.
- After 10 secs Camera close with no data and back to menu.

I already created my camera functionally but I don't know how to apply countdown timer to stop the camera after 10 secs.

So please lend me your help, thanks.

Comment: you need to create custom camera view to take pictures and add your 10 seconds logic inside.

Comment: can you give me an link or example, i already created my camera so it could waste if i just delete my camera thanks

Comment: In this case you will have to implement your own Camera preview instead of launching the camera app so that you will have control of all these things.

Comment: A simple google search will give a hundreds of exampls on Camera API . Here is one https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

Comment: thanks i will give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Android documentation clearly explains how to use the apis

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect

Of course you will need a timer or an alarm to close the camera.

Use timer alarm not required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
mCountdowntimer=new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod, 1000) {//countdown Period =5000

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                textView.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }

            public void onFinish() {

                 mediaplayer.stop(); }

        }.start();
```